# How do I fix the situation where my chairlift has a long station, but only one car

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

Recently, upon reinstalling *Rollercoaster Tycoon 2*, I was playing a scenario where I built a point-to-point chairlift that went from one end of my park to another. Much to my chagrin, despite having twelve tiles of station at both ends, there was only one car. I tried resetting the ride. I tried rebuilding sections of it. But in the end, the configuration only let me set one car. There were a few other people who had posted the same problem online, but no solution was provided.

So, how do I fix the problem where only one chair is available?

Comment: You state a problem, but you don't actually specify a question.

Comment: My apologies. Probably since I had the solution in mind (this was an issue that I ran into a few days ago, and just realized would be useful to archive here), I wasn't thinking in terms of questions, but rather problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more fiddling around, I realized the simple issue. I'd built one of my stations backwards somehow. From the game's perspective, I had hooked up two single-tile stations together. Rebuilding the stations solved the problem.

Comment: This did not help me with the same question. I have a station with entrance and exit and then a line to another station with exit and entrance. (not a loop). And still only gives me 1 chair. Why? And no option to add more.